# How to prevent the spellcheck website wordcounter.net from saving the text?

Tags: privacy, spell-check

A year ago, I copied a small text in [`https://wordcounter.net`](https://wordcounter.net) to count the number of words. Recently, I wanted to use this site again, and I noticed that my previous text was still there.

Is there a way to prevent my text from being saved? I read the [Privacy policy](https://wordcounter.net/blog/privacy-policy) but cannot find any information about the text being saved and being redisplayed the next time (based on IP address?).

Comment: @Rubén It's about `wordcounter.net` (although it could apply to other sites as well), so I've modified the title.

Comment: Are you sure it is IP address tracking with server-side storage?  A simple test would be to open a web browser in Private/Incognito mode and navigate to [wordcounter.net](https://wordcounter.net).  If you are indeed correct, you should see the same stored text that you are describing. Let me know the result.

Comment: @BlindSpots You are right! No text is shown when opening `wordcounter.net` in a private window (or in an other browser).

Comment: run the next test I described in [my answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/169655/) to see if it can be tied to a cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Not tracking by IP

Following your test using a private session from the same IP, we can determine that it isn't your IP address triggering some server-side reload of your previous content.

I suspect that it isn't server-side at all but rather client-side.  For example, when you last visited the site a cookie may have been saved in your browser with the information that is being loaded.

You can test this by deleting any cookies that this site might have stored:

[Delete cookies from a specific site in Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=:%7E:text=Delete%20cookies%20from%20a%20site)

1. Open **chrome settings** <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> then <kbd>s</kbd>
2. Click **Privacy and security**, then **Cookies and other site data**
3. Click **"See all site data and permissions"**
4. At the top right, search for the website's name
5. To the right of the site, click **Remove**
6. To confirm, click **Clear**.

Comment: Indeed, the text on `wordcounter.net` is no longer available after removing the cookie as described here!